# ubuntu: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, firefox, geckodriver

I have firefox installed and geckodriver.exe in the same directory. The same code works in windows but when i try to use it in ubuntu i have the following error:  `'geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.`

the code is the following:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

url = 'https://www.idealista.com/venta-viviendas/barcelona/eixample/la-dreta-de-l-eixample/?ordenado-por=fecha-publicacion-desc'
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'geckodriver')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
```

i've tried using the same code without calling gecko with r: driver = `webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='geckodriver')`

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't use driver with extension `.exe`.

Comment: I use Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu) and in home directory I have folder `bin` - `/home/furas/bin` and I have it assigned to `PATH` in file `.bashrc` - and now I can put all my executable programs and scripts in this folder and system can find it. And in this folder I keep drivers for `firefox`, `chrome`, `edge`

Answer (score 1):

You can use webdriverManager, it's  up-to-date and no need binary driver extension.So it will never show the error like you are getting:`geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.` You have to install `selenium4` and `pip install webdriver-manager`

```
#selenium4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()),options=options)


url = 'https://www.idealista.com/venta-viviendas/barcelona/eixample/la-dreta-de-l-eixample/?ordenado-por=fecha-publicacion-desc'
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
```

[webdriverManager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Comment: I've tried this approach but I still get a similar error:

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

Answer (score 1):

Using the complete path solved the problem

```
import time    
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options      
url = 'https://www.idealista.com/venta-viviendas/barcelona/eixample/la-dreta-de-l-eixample/?ordenado-por=fecha-publicacion-desc'    
options = Options()    
options.headless = False    
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='/home/kevin/Desktop/Inmosoft/geckodriver')    
driver.get(url)    
time.sleep(10)
```